# How should I manipulate a nested json input using logstash

Tags: json, logstash

I want to use `logstash` for creating an output json from my nested input json.

Assuming my input `json` looks something like:

```
{
    "firstnestedprop": {
        "secondnestedprop": {
            "thirdnestedprop": {
                "key": "value",
                "key2": "value2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to output something like:

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

Or something like:

```
{
    "keys": ["key", "key2"],
    "values": ["value", "value2"]
}
```

What plugin should I use?

Can anyone provide a short example or reference me to some relevant documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out using the [ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html), since my case was a bit more complicated than the example I've posted (included nested arrays and complex objects). I'm not sure if there's a better way or not, but I have tried most of the filters and the [ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) was the only one that I felt good with (the others involved regular expressions and other ugly things).

Comment: Can you give an example how exactly you got it work with this plugin? Did you use the `code` setting and code in ruby?